# How to display data in listview in android return using a web service?

Tags: android

My web service: `shreeomex.com/service.asmx`
I am not able to display it in a list view. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        //this is the actual part that will call the webservice
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION1, envelope);

        // Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.
        SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
        result = (SoapObject) result.getProperty(1);
        table = (SoapObject) result.getProperty(0);
         tableRow = (SoapObject) table.getProperty(0);
        if(result != null)
        {
            //Get the first property and change the label text


                try {
                    SAXParserFactory saxparser = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
                    SAXParser parser = saxparser.newSAXParser();
                    XMLReader xmlReader = parser.getXMLReader();
                    ParsingClass pc = new ParsingClass();
                    xmlReader.setContentHandler(pc);
                            String xml= result.toString();  ss.setText(xml);
                              StringReader sr = new StringReader(xml);
                                InputSource is = new InputSource(sr);
                                is.setEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
                                xmlReader.parse(is);


                // InputStream is = getAssets().open("service.xml");
                    //  xmlReader.parse(new InputSource(is));
                    BindingData bindingData = new BindingData(this, pc.CompanyId,
                            pc.CompanyName, pc.IsActive);
                    listView.setAdapter(bindingData);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    ss.setText(e.toString());
                    e.getMessage();
                }
            }  

    }
```

Comment: need to see your BindingData class

Comment: but if i will pass  service.xml in inputstream then it works fine.. I want to display with the xml retuns by my web service.. so there is no problem with binding data class

Comment: <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
<NewDataSet xmlns="">
<Table diffgr:id="Table1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
<CompanyId>1</CompanyId>
<CompanyName>Bajaj Allianz Insurance Co.Limited</CompanyName>
<CompSHortName>Bajaj</CompSHortName>
<IsActive>true</IsActive>
<InsertDate>2012-09-06T11:09:32.87+05:30</InsertDate>
</Table>

Comment: result.tostring returns data in these format simmiler to these:anyType{ProductName=anyType{Text=Nadolol; Code=anyType{Value=11755; 
CodingSystem=FDB_routed; }; Code=anyType{Value=20.55472; 
CodingSystem=Google; }; Code=anyType{Value=7870; CodingSystem=FDB; }; 
Code=anyType{Value=19.9453; CodingSystem=Google; }; }; }